# ProgressDialog background for the top layout

Tags: android, imageview, progressdialog

I am trying to make a ProgressDialog having a loading animation by rotating an ImageView.

My problem is that the ImageView background is getting the root view background and not the background of the top layout that the user see. This problem started only from Android 5 and I can't find any solution to this.

How can I change it?

The image for the ProgressDialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/loading_blue"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ImageView>
```

The main page layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_background" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/app_blue" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/chatsList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:transcriptMode="disabled" >
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/social_background"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my dialog code:

```
public static ProgressDialog setLoadingPogressDialog(Context context) {

    ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
    pDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    View v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.loading_new, null);

    pDialog.setContentView(v);

    v.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.rotate360));
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    return pDialog;
}
```

[image]

Comment: is this `loading_blue` image a `png` with transparent background or a `jpg`?

Comment: it have transparent  background

Comment: can you post the code of `loading_new.xml` ?